# ESP32's GPIO pins won't respond

Tags: led, oscilloscope, programming, gpio, esp32

I connected three LEDs to 3 GPIO pins in the ESP32. They used to blink as expect previously. But now, they don't. The code is as follows.

```
//Testing ESP32's LEDs

const int redPin = 25;
const int greenPin = 26;
const int bluePin = 27;

void setup() {
  pinMode (redPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (greenPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (bluePin, OUTPUT);
}
void loop() {
  digitalWrite (redPin, HIGH);  // turn on the LED
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite (redPin, LOW); // turn off the LED
  delay(1000);

  digitalWrite (greenPin, HIGH);  // turn on the LED
  delay(1000); 
  digitalWrite (greenPin, LOW); // turn off the LED
  delay(1000);

  digitalWrite (bluePin, HIGH);  // turn on the LED
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite (bluePin, LOW); // turn off the LED
  delay(1000); 
}
```

I checked whether there is a voltage going through the GPIO pins. Turns out it just spike up for a short while and goes back to zero. Then goes to a negative voltage and goes back to zero.

[image]

Any idea what might be the cause of this?

Comment: Coupling = AC change to DC and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. The 'scope CH1 coupling is set to AC.*

This switches a capacitor in series with the input. A positive going square edge causes the input to rise with it but discharge at a time set by the 'scope's input capacitance and resistance. A similar effect happens on the falling edge.

Switching to DC coupling should fix it.